# REACT Array True or False Inputs?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, radio-button

Im having difficulty serializing my inputs and saving it on my API. I cant manage to make it work.
Need some advice or inputs how to do this with arrays or even another simpler way.

I having problem how to put the radio button input array data into my postData that will be save to my API

postData is questionid, questiontype and answers

Questions:

1.Earth is flat? True False
2.Earth is round? True False

so my input is radio button like this

```
handleTF(event) {
 const tfc = event.target.value;
 console.log(event.target.name)
 console.log(tfc);
 this.setState({ [event.target.name]: tfc});
}

const tfcs = ["True", "False"]

{tfcs.map((tfc, index) => (
  <label key={index}>
     {tfc}
       <input
         name={qd.question.id} 
           value={tfc}
           onChange={this.handleTF}
           type="radio"
        />
   </label>
))}

handleSubmitTF(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        const {
            questionId,
            questionType,
            answer
        } = this.state;

        const postData = {

            questionId,
            questionType,
            answer,

        };

        let sessionToken = sessionStorage.getItem('session');
        let sessToken = sessionToken.replace(/\"/g, "");

        fetch('sample.net', {

        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'token'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify([postData]),
        })

        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.title)
            if(response.title === "Error"){
                this.addNotification('danger', 'Danger', 'Already answered', 'top-right')
            }else{
                this.addNotification('success', 'Success', 'All Data is Saved', 'top-right')
                this.componentDidMount();
            }

        })      
        .catch(err => {

            console.log("fetch error" + err);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Context

It seems that your state is made of:

```js
{ [event.target.name]: "True" | "False" }
```

But then you access it with:

```js
const {
    questionId,
    questionType,
    answer
} = this.state;
```

They do not match type / interface. In TypeScript terms your State looks like:

```js
interface State {
  [k: string]: "True" | "False";
}
```

### Solutions

#### A. Send your state directly

As it has a valid structure, it would be easy to parse on the API side.

```js
const postData = { ...this.state };
```

#### B. Send an Array of answers

Otherwise, if you need it as an Array of answers. You can transform it like:

```js
const questions = Object.keys(this.state);

const postData = questions.map((question) => ({
  question,
  answer: this.state[name],
}));
```

---

*Side note: Earth is flat, and it is called Discworld =o)*

Comment: your a lifesaver, im getting stressed out with this. new in react

Comment: Glad it helps! _"Practice makes the master"_, don't give up :)